# Android: Interact with another app?

Tags: android, interaction

I'm looking to build an app that will restart my device at a specified time, then open up a couple 3rd party apps in sequence and run their feature/s.

*For example: I would like to automatically restart my phone at 5am. Then have it open an antivirus app of my choice and run the scan. Then close that app and open up another app and run it's cleaner function.*

I have experience coding, but I'm just starting to take a peak into android app development. So, I was wondering if this is something feasible to do.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Waht you want to do is called an `intent`. Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the starting phone at the desired time, but I am sure you can start applications on boot using "init". Linux systems support that, and android does as well. But it completely depends on your kernel.

1. [Read here](http://androidcreations.weebly.com/initd-support-explained.html) about init.d.
2. Check if your phone's kernel supports init.d. [Check here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1933849) if your phone doesn't have init.d support.
3. [Check Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot) for running a script at boot. It is quite useful for custom scripts.
4. [Check Here](https://iamcmotc.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-how-to-run-script-or-system.html) for running scripts/application the application at boot

Create a script according to your needs and I think you would be able to achieve what you are looking for. <- Custom Rules

I would have commented but apparently I can not since I am new here.
I hope I was of some help. Will look into the android starting part and get back to you.
Cheers.